# Ajax ready state 0 only in doplhin bromwser android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, dolphin-browser

I have 6 ajax calls that are called from jquery to an MVC Home controller the first 5 work fine but when I get to the last one I get the following errors: I have tried jsonp but don't see why this works in every browser but not in Dolphin Browser for android.

ajax "readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"

The setup is as follows iis server hosts the website and another server with the data which I access using webservices, these are on the same domain.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is triggering the Ajax call?

Comment: A button click I have tried e.preventdefault().

Comment: Tried on Samsung Tab 2 using 4.2.2 and dolphin 10.2.7 works fine. Nexus 7 4.4.2 and dolphin 10.2.7 doesn't work.

Comment: it is `e.preventDefault()`.... You have the uppercase D?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my comment I used uppercase D